# Clause libarary database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a clause library wherein I want to store all the clause definitions.

Basically, I have 3 kinds of clauses: Global, Regional and Country specific.
Regional (4) and Country (100+) specific clauses change their definition(description) based on the regions and country.

My task is to create a clause library in which all the variation of the clauses can be saved and retrieve based on some condition.

**Example:**
Global : "AAC"
AMS Region: "AAC"
APJ Region: "ABB"
EMEA region: "BBB"
US (AMS) : "AAC"
Canada (AMS) : "ABA"
...

If the user opt for global deal, "AAA" is selected. "ABB" is selected when a APJ combine deal is selected and "ABA" is only selected if the Canada as a country is selected. (Can be handle at API level). Nevertheless, I need to store all the desc into the DB.

Note: The strings can be common (like first and last letter in the above example) insame in most of the cases. Variations can occur in the middle letter or sometime the complete string.

I want a design in which I can store all these variances.

Comment: Ok.  If you have a question, feel free to post one on Stack Overflow.  In the meantime, this description should be deleted because it is not a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry not to be specific. I want a db design structure which can handle all the variances.